# Azure Logic App SQL Connector retries

Tags: sql, azure

Does the built in SQL Connector have a built in retry mechanism? If not, is it acceptable to simply use a Do-until until status is ok or it maxed out on the configured Do-until count is reached?

Answer (score 0):

Seems all I have to do is use the retry policy available for http actions and Api apps